# What is the difference between HOMO-LUMO Energy gap and Forbidden (Energy) gap?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, orbitals

I have found a similar question on a different website upon searching on google but it didn't clear my confusion (which might be because I didn't understand the explanation). 
(PS: I am a 12th STD Student)

So, how exactly do they differ? Can they ever be equal?

HOMO- Highest Occupied Molecular Orbital
LUMO- Lowest Unoccupied Molecular Orbital

Forbidden gap - Energy difference between the highest energy conduction band and lowest energy valence band.

So, why aren't these the same?

Answer (score 1):

The HOMO-LUMO gap is a computational number. It gives the energy of a band gap excitation without any relaxation and many electron correlation effects such an excitation may exhibit. These effects are very hard to calculate. I don't know of any calculation that correctly predicts band gaps to within say 20%. Maybe my literature knowledge needs an update, though.